# dynamic codeigniter select not working

Tags: codeigniter, dynamic

```
controller
car.php

<?php  
   class Car extends CI_Controller {  
   public function __construct()  
   {  
      parent::__construct();  
      $this->load->database();  
      $this->load->helper('url');  
      $this->load->helper('form');  
      $this->load->model('company_model');  
   }  
   public function index()  
   {  
      //starts by running the query for the countries  
      //dropdown  
      $data['companydrop'] = $this->company_model->company();  
      //loads up the view with the query results  
      $this->load->view('car_view', $data);  
   }  
   //call to fill the second dropdown with the cities  
   public function car_model()  
   {  
      //set selected country id from POST  
      echo $company_id = $this->input->post('company_id',TRUE);  
      //run the query for the cities we specified earlier  
      $cardata['cardrop']=$this->company_model->car($company_id);  
      print_r($cardata);
      $output = null;  
      foreach ($cardata['cardrop'] as $row)  
      {  
         //here we build a dropdown item line for each  
        // query result  
         $output .= "<option value='".$row->car_model."'>".$row->car_model."</option>";  
      }  
      echo $output;  
   }  
}  
?>


model
company_model
<?php  
class Company_model extends CI_Model {  
   public function __construct()  
   {  
      $this->load->database();  
   }  
   //fill your contry dropdown  
   public function company()  
   {  
      $this->db->select('company_id,company_name');  
      $this->db->from('company');  
      $query = $this->db->get();  
      // the query mean select cat_id,category from  
      //category  
      foreach($query->result_array() as $row){  
         $data[$row['company_id']]=$row['company_name'];  
      }  
      // the fetching data from database is return  
      return $data;  
   }  
   //fill your cities dropdown depending on the selected city  
   public function car($company_id=string)  
   {  
      $this->db->select('car_id,car_model');  
      $this->db->from('car');  
      $this->db->where('company',$company_id);  
      $query = $this->db->get();  
      return $query->result();  
   }  
}  

?>
 view 
car_view

<html>
<head>
<title>car dealers</title>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>  
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>  
               <script type="text/javascript">  
                  $(document).ready(function() {  
                     $("#companydrop").change(function(){  
                     /*dropdown post *///  
                     $.ajax({  
                        url:"<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/car/car_model",

                        data: {id:$(this).val()},  
                        type: "POST",  
                        success:function(data){  
                        $("#cardrop").html(data);
                    alert(data);

                     }  
                  });  
               });  
            });  


</script>
<style>
body{


        no-repeat;
        background:url(../../../video-fallback-background.jpg)

    }
</style>
</head>
<body>

      <!--company dropdown-->  
      <?php echo form_dropdown('companydrop',$companydrop,'','class="required" id="companydrop"'); ?>  
      <br />  
      <br />  
      <!--car dropdown-->  
      <select name="cardrop" id="cardrop">  
         <option value="">Select</option>  
      </select>  
      <br /> 
   </body>  
</html>
```

dynamic dropdown is not working as the first select which is the 
company name is working as it is fetched from database,but car model is not working,it not fetched to the dropdown.i need to fetch the car company model from database and then after selecting the company the model of that specified company has to be listed in the second dropdown.i have created database in phpmyadmin and created two table car and company,in company copany_id and company_name where as in car has car_id,car_name and company_id

Comment: did you get value in data after ajax call ?
if so use  $("#cardrop").append(data); and try. also remove all your echo and print from car_model function except echo $data

Comment: how to check whether ajax response is success

Comment: what is the output off $data ?

Comment: $data s ouptput is 'company name' from the table 'company' in database

Comment: Please paste output of console.log($data). Also are u able to see alert box?

Answer (score 0):

Check this sample code for creating dropdown in codeigniter.

```
<?php
$js = 'id="unicode" class="form-control"';
$unicode = array(
'2' => 'No',
'1' => 'Yes'
);
echo form_dropdown('unicode', $unicode, set_value('unicode'), $js);
?>
```

Here Dropdown id is unicode,class is form-control.

Html will look like :

```
<select name="unicode" id="unicode" class="form-control">
<option value="2">No</option>
<option value="1">Yes</option>
</select>
```

You can get you values from db in an array and then store it in a variable like `$unicode`.Hope this helps.Check this ref [link](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/form_helper.html)

For setting another dropdown based on first dropdown:

```
$("#dropdown1").change(function () {
    var end = this.value;
    $('#dropdown2').val(end );         
});
```

Comment: thnx for ur reply,but in my code first select is working but the second dropdown has to change based on the first dropdown .could you please give me simple example like that.as i am new to codeigniter, i dont know..

Comment: For this you have to use jquery **.change**

Comment: Instead of $("#cardrop").html(data); use $("#cardrop").val(data);

Answer (score 0):

In Your Car Controller Please remove `print_r($cardata);` first.
Then see in your console what response you are getting from the call. I suggest you to get data in json format and parse it on client end. It is the best practice.

Comment: thers is no print_r($cardata) in my controller to remove

Comment: some one else edited it, sorry,in my actual code its not there

Comment: Have you checked in your console what data sent and what you are receiving?

Comment: parameter is passing as if i select any item in first select box that id is passing but not getting anything.. no response but Parametersapplication/x-www-form-urlencoded
id 4
Source
id=4    ,i think the problwm is with the the model ,result is not passing to controller aging to display in view , i think,

Comment: `echo $this->db->last_query();` to see what query is executing for the request.

Answer (score 0):

```
i corrected the code and finally it worked,i will post the correct code, if it helps anyone in future.thanks to everyone who tried to help me..

controller

car.php



 <?php  
class Car extends CI_Controller {  
public function __construct()  
{  

    parent::__construct();  
    $this->load->database();  
    $this->load->helper('url');  
    $this->load->helper('form');  
    $this->load->model('company_model');  
    }  
    public function index()  
    {  


    $data['companydrop'] = $this->company_model->company();  

    $this->load->view('car_view', $data);  
    }  

    public function car_model()  
    {  

    $company_id = $this->input->post('company_id',TRUE);  

    $cardata['cardrop']=$this->company_model->car($company_id);


    $output = null;  

    foreach ($cardata['cardrop'] as $row)  
    {  

    $output .= "<option value='".$row->car_model."'>".$row->car_model."</option>";  

    }  
    echo $output;
    }  

    }  
    ?>

model
company_model

        <?php  
    class Company_model extends CI_Model {  
    public function __construct()  
    {  
    $this->load->database();  
    }  

    public function company()  
    {  
    $this->db->select('company_id,company_name');  
    $this->db->from('company');  
    $query = $this->db->get();  


    foreach($query->result_array() as $row){  
       $data[$row['company_id']]=$row['company_name'];  
    }  

    return $data;  
    }  

    public function car($company_id)  
    {


    $this->db->select('car_id,car_model');  
    $this->db->from('car');  
    $this->db->where('company_id',$company_id); 


    $query = $this->db->get();  

    return $query->result();  
    }  
    }  

    ?>


view
car_view



     <html>
    <head>
    <title>car dealers</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>  
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>  
    <script type="text/javascript">  
    $(document).ready(function() {  


    $("#companydrop").change(function(){  


    /*dropdown post *///  
    $.ajax({  

       url:"<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/car/car_model",                       
       data: {company_id:$(this).val()},  
       type: "POST",  
       success:function(data){ 
               $('#cardrop option[value!=0]').remove()
           $("#cardrop").append(data);  


          }  
       });  
    });  
    });  


    </script>
    <style>
    body{       

    no-repeat;
    background:url(../../../video-fallback-background.jpg)

    }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
      <center><font color="#333366"><strong></strong><h2>CR Motors</h2></font></center>
    <center><font color="#FF8000"><h3>Select the car to purchase...</h3></center></font>
    <!--company dropdown-->  
    <tr>
    <td>
    <font color="#00FF99">
    Select the company</font>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 
    <?php echo form_dropdown('companydrop',$companydrop,'','class="required" id="companydrop"'); ?>  </td>
     </tr>  
    <br />  
    <br />  
    <!--car dropdown-->  
    <tr>
    <td>
    <font color="#00FF99">
    Select the model</font>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <select name="cardrop" id="cardrop">  
    <option value="0">Select</option>  

    </select>
    </td>
     </tr>  
    <br />  
    </body>  
    </html>
```

Comment: can anyone help how can i load picture after when i select any car model from the second drop down,any suggestion,wht should i do??